# Can you update the backgrounds of your GridViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, wear-os

In my Adroid Wear application I have a `GridViewPager` and a custom `FragmentGridPagerAdapter`. I instantiate my adpater when I launch the application and I update its content later when my handheld application provide new data.

The text of the different pages is correctly updated since the method `getFragment` is called everytime we switch to a new page. On the contrary `getBackground` seems to be called only when the adapter is instantiated which means I can't update my pages' backgrounds :/

Any ideas how I can tell the adapter to update all (or idealy only one) background ?

--- EDIT ---

Here's my code :
My `GridViewPager` is the provided one, I didn't change anything in it (maybe that's where I shound investigate)

Page:

```
public class Page {

    public String mTitle;
    public String mText;
    public int mIconId = 0;
    public int mBackgroundId;

    public Page(String title, String text, int iconId, int backgroundId) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mText = text;
        this.mIconId = iconId;
        this.mBackgroundId = backgroundId;
    }

    public Page(String title, String text, int backgroundId) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mText = text;
        this.mBackgroundId = backgroundId;
    }
}
```

Row:

```
public class Row {

    ArrayList<Page> mPagesRow = new ArrayList<Page>();

    public void addPages(Page page) {
        mPagesRow.add(page);
    }

    public Page getPages(int index) {
        return mPagesRow.get(index);
    }

    public int size(){
        return mPagesRow.size();
    }
}
```

GridPagerAdapter:

```
public class GridPagerAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "GridPagerAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Row> mPages;

    public GridPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mContext = context;
        initPages();
    }

    private void initPages() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initPages");
        mPages = new ArrayList<Row>();
        Row row;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            row = new Row();
            row.addPages(new Page("card #"+i,"lorem ipsum",R.color.black));
            row.addPages(new Page("card #"+i,"page 2",R.color.black));
            mPages.add(row);
        }
    }

    private void updatePages() {
        Log.d(TAG, "updatePages");
        mPages = new ArrayList<Row>();
        Row row;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            row = new Row();
            row.addPages(new Page("updated card #"+i,"lorem ipsum",R.color.white));
            row.addPages(new Page("updated card #"+i,"page 2",R.color.white));
            mPages.add(row);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getFragment("+row+","+col+")");
        Fragment fragment;
        Page page = mPages.get(row).getPages(col);
        fragment = (page.mIconId > 0 ? CardFragment.create(page.mTitle, page.mText, page.mIconId) : CardFragment.create(page.mTitle, page.mText));
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageReference getBackground(int row, int col) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getBackground("+row+","+col+")");
        Page page = mPages.get(row).getPages(col);
        return ImageReference.forDrawable(page.mBackgroundId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return mPages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int row) {
        return mPages.get(row).size();
    }

}
```

When I use updatePages, the texts in my gridview changes but not my backgrounds.

Comment: Can you provide more details/code of your implementation?

Comment: Sure, but it very classic I think.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the provided example

```
{sdk_root}/samples/android-20/wearable/GridViewPager
```

The method

```
 public ImageReference getBackground(int row, int col)
       return new YourFragment();
       ...
```

And

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
        rootView.setBackground(yourDrawable);
        return rootView;
    }
```

is according to the row of the grid- the idea is to have one "story" in a row and every of this stories has an own background image.

If you wanna change this, you should use custom Cardfragments with an own background in your

```
public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col)
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried but in that case I lose the transitions betweens the backgrounds...

Comment: What do you mean by loosing the transition? I edited my answer maybe it`s now more helpful.

Comment: Ok I understand your answer and the problem was that my question wasn't very clear. I'd like to have a different background for each  fragment (using getBackground from the adapter) and I would like to update them later on.

Comment: I feel like with your answer I would only have a single background for the whole pager...

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the background of the gridviewpager, but you can wrap it in a Linear Layout and set the background of the linear layout.

Example below..

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackgroundimage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
       android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:keepScreenOn="true"
       tools:context=".GridActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```